# Javascript: trigger some action if the user press twice on shiftKey

Tags: javascript

I want to trigger some action if the user press twice on shiftKey.

This code working when i press on shiftKey once but how to make this work for twice

```
top.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
   if(e.shiftKey) {
     alert('work');
   }
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set timer and detect if key is pressed again in that interval.

```
var twice_16 = 0;

$(document).on('keyup', function (e) {

        if (e.which === 16) { // shift    

            if (twice_16 === 1) { // (remember that twice_16 is 0 initially)
                alert('Do something! (you pressed Left twice!)');
            }

            twice_16 = 1; // Set to 1 and...
            setTimeout(function () { // ...reset to 0 after 1s
                twice_16 = 0;
            }, 1000);

        }

    });
```

Working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/sachinnambiar/6a0m73nh/1/

Taken from :
[How to detect: Press twice the same key, but hold it the second time for 2 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16454375/how-to-detect-press-twice-the-same-key-but-hold-it-the-second-time-for-2-secon)

Answer (score 0):

**You can use mousetrap.js to simplify key events**

https://craig.is/killing/mice

Binding two consecutive <kbd>shift</kbd> key press with **mousetrap.js** can be quickly written as:

```
Mousetrap.bind('shift shift', function(e) {
    // Do something
});
```